# Getting error message while running GRASS command?

Tags: grass-gis, windows, gui, windows-8

**I'm using GRASS 6.4.3(installed with OSGeo4W) under Windows 8.1 x64.**

When I type commands in the command console below, I often face these problems：

1. type command which has "space", like：**g.list rast**, as I type "space" (the command was not finished), the output window always shows error message like this：

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\PROGRA~2\QUANTU~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\w
   xpython\gui_core\prompt.py", line 1133, in OnKeyPressed

   self.cmdDesc = gtask.parse_interface(GetRealCmd(cmd))
   File "C:\PROGRA~2\QUANTU~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\p
   ython\grass\script\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

   tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
   File "C:\PROGRA~2\QUANTU~1\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\Ele
   mentTree.py", line 1282, in XML

   parser.feed(text)
   File "C:\PROGRA~2\QUANTU~1\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\Ele
   mentTree.py", line 1624, in feed

   self._raiseerror(v)
   File "C:\PROGRA~2\QUANTU~1\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\Ele
   mentTree.py", line 1488, in _raiseerror

   raise err
   xml.etree.ElementTree
   .
   ParseError
   :
   unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
2. As I finish the command, I press "enter", and the same error message shows. In many times, I press "enter" to run the module more than one time or I clear the output window before I run the module, the same error message still came out.

Although I could get results what I want, but it's very annoying having these problems, and **I don't know why the same error message show up？ And how to fix it？**

**Are these problems in relation to WIN8.1 or something else？**

---

My GRASS GUI is very unstable as it often shows problems I post above, here's the detailed output log as I use **r.category** command,

```
(Tue Mar 25 10:59:11 2014)                                                      
r.category b1                                                                   
1   
(Tue Mar 25 10:59:12 2014) Command finished (0 sec)                             
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 1122, in OnKeyPressed

self._runCmd(self.GetCurLine()[0].strip())
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 623, in _runCmd

self.parent.RunCmd(cmd)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\goutput.py", line 554, in RunCmd

task = GUI(show = None).ParseCommand(command)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 1871, in ParseCommand

blackList = _blackList)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python\grass\s
cript\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1300, in XML

parser.feed(text)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1642, in feed

self._raiseerror(v)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1506, in _raiseerror

raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree
.
ParseError
:
unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 1122, in OnKeyPressed

self._runCmd(self.GetCurLine()[0].strip())
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 623, in _runCmd

self.parent.RunCmd(cmd)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\goutput.py", line 554, in RunCmd

task = GUI(show = None).ParseCommand(command)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 1871, in ParseCommand

blackList = _blackList)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python\grass\s
cript\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1300, in XML

parser.feed(text)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1642, in feed

self._raiseerror(v)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1506, in _raiseerror

raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree
.
ParseError
:
unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 1122, in OnKeyPressed

self._runCmd(self.GetCurLine()[0].strip())
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 623, in _runCmd

self.parent.RunCmd(cmd)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\goutput.py", line 554, in RunCmd

task = GUI(show = None).ParseCommand(command)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 1871, in ParseCommand

blackList = _blackList)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python\grass\s
cript\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1300, in XML

parser.feed(text)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1642, in feed

self._raiseerror(v)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1506, in _raiseerror

raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree
.
ParseError
:
unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 1122, in OnKeyPressed

self._runCmd(self.GetCurLine()[0].strip())
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 623, in _runCmd

self.parent.RunCmd(cmd)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\goutput.py", line 554, in RunCmd

task = GUI(show = None).ParseCommand(command)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 1871, in ParseCommand

blackList = _blackList)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python\grass\s
cript\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1300, in XML

parser.feed(text)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1642, in feed

self._raiseerror(v)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1506, in _raiseerror

raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree
.
ParseError
:
unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 1122, in OnKeyPressed

self._runCmd(self.GetCurLine()[0].strip())
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 623, in _runCmd

self.parent.RunCmd(cmd)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\goutput.py", line 554, in RunCmd

task = GUI(show = None).ParseCommand(command)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 1871, in ParseCommand

blackList = _blackList)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python\grass\s
cript\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1300, in XML

parser.feed(text)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1642, in feed

self._raiseerror(v)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1506, in _raiseerror

raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree
.
ParseError
:
unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 1122, in OnKeyPressed

self._runCmd(self.GetCurLine()[0].strip())
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\prompt.py", line 623, in _runCmd

self.parent.RunCmd(cmd)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\goutput.py", line 554, in RunCmd

task = GUI(show = None).ParseCommand(command)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 1871, in ParseCommand

blackList = _blackList)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python\grass\s
cript\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1300, in XML

parser.feed(text)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1642, in feed

self._raiseerror(v)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1506, in _raiseerror

raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree
.
ParseError
:
unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
(Tue Mar 25 10:59:16 2014)                                                      
r.category b4                                                                   
1   
(Tue Mar 25 10:59:17 2014) Command finished (0 sec)
```

The log shows that after **r.category b1** successfully runs, I try to run **r.category b4** but get the same error once I press enter. After error messages show up many times, I finally get the result.

I don't know the meaning of the error, and **how to fix it or improve its stability via these errors.**
 **Does this in relation with my platform？, and are there someone successfully and smoothly using GRASS under Windows 8.1 x64？**

Answer (score 3):

As I answered to another of your questions, please update to the official release first which is GRASS GIS 6.4.3. It is difficult to give you any suggestion on a release candidate.

See the official release news here: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/6.4.3-News

If the problem persists, please report.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, and I've downloaded GRASS 6.4.3-1 from this website：http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/binary/mswindows/native/ linked from your answer. But after the installation, I only open GRASS 6.4.3 successfully once, except this new problem, the old problems still exists, so I don't know what reason cause these...

Comment: I am working with WIN8.1 64bits, and GRASS installation guided me to install it in this path：C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS GIS 6.4.3, I don't know if this is the reason?

Comment: I unistalled GRASS and installed again, this time I choose to install it directly under C:\, but I can not open it.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I can't open GRASS, but the candidate version could be opened.

Comment: I mean GRASS did not respond after I click its icon.

Comment: hello, I have posted my question in detail：http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86703/cant-launch-grass-gis-6-4-3-gui-on-windows-8-1, please give me some suggestions, thank you!

Comment: dear markusN I have installed GRASS 6.4.3(stable version), but the problem in my post still show up sometimes

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS installed, too? There seems to sometimes occur conflicts with the different Python version coming with ArcGIS and GRASS GIS...

Comment: thank you for your advice, so I need to try to uninstall ArcGIS...

Comment: after uninstall ArcGIS, GRASS still have problems in my post sometimes, should reinstall GRASS?

Comment: Yes, please try that. I really hope that we can sort out these conflicting Python problems. See also the related discussion in http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2014-February/thread.html#67136

Comment: I've reinstalled GRASS but there are still problems I posted, and furthermore, after reinstallation twice, r.watershed module begins to export broken data(basin, half_basin and streams)

Comment: Please explain what "broken data" means for you... r.watershed generates data in the GRASS format and does not export.

Comment: I found that r.watershed generates "broken data" because I input the file which is in permanent mapset, and as I input the other one in customized mapset, everything goes right.

Comment: Raster maps can be in "any" mapset within the current location. You can either specify an input map as "map@mapset", or, if you want to simplify it, add that "mapset" to the search path with the g.mapsets command. r.watershed hardly generates "broken data", perhaps it simply did not find the input? What was the error message? Note that output is always written to the current mapset.