# Launching GRASS GIS 6.4.3 GUI on windows 8.1?

Tags: grass-gis, windows-8, gui

I downloaded GRASS GIS from this website：
[GRASS GIS - Home](http://grass.osgeo.org/news/28/15/Stable-GRASS-GIS-6-4-3-released/), and I choose **winGRASS 6.4.3 standalone installer** to download.

After I installed, I click on its icon：
[image]

I can't launch it even though I have used 2 ways：

1. just left-click the mouse
2. right-click the icon and choose **start as an administrator**

**can't launch** means after I click the icon, the cmd icon shows up in less than one second on the windows bar below(even no windows come up), and then nothing comes up.

[image]

This really bothers me because I can't open GRASS!

I'm working under windows 8.1, is there someone using windows 8.1 facing the same problem like mine?

Comment: Without error message it remains a black box... Could you start it from "cmd" to see if any error message is hidden from the "normal" view?

Comment: When I tried to start Grass GIS GUI, there is a message launching that "python.exe has stopped working". I am using windows 8.1. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: In general you need to *install* GRASS GIS as an administrator.

Comment: I had the same problem. I have installed GRASS GIS 7.0.0. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: we have collected a series of related questions and answers at

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WinGRASS_errors

Hope the page addresses 99% of the issues you may encounter :-)